# Contain Resource in Executable

Tags: c++, xcode

In Objective-C you can use NSBundle to find the path to a resource inside your app. I'm using Xcode but I'm creating a command line tool in C++. I need to access the text files in my project. How can I do this? I need to access the "About" file in one of my C++ classes.
[image: Screenshot of project]